How to properly use Pinia store in root vue component?
My main.ts:
import './assets/tailwind.css'
import './assets/wordpress.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')

And I'm trying to use a store in App.vue:
<script setup lang="ts">
import NavigationBar from '@/components/navigation/NavigationBar.vue'
import TopBar from '@/components/header/TopBar.vue'
import NavigationDrawer from '@/components/navigation/NavigationDrawer.vue'
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import ErrorSnackbar from '@/components/ErrorSnackbar.vue'
import { useUser } from '@/stores/user'

const router = useRouter();
const route = useRoute()

onMounted(() => {
  const user = useUser()
  user.signInSilent()
});
</script>

But I'm getting following error:
Uncaught Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Are you trying to use a store before calling "app.use(pinia)"?
See https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html for help.
This will fail in production.
    useStore pinia.mjs:1709
    <anonymous> user.ts:9
pinia.mjs:1709:18
    useStore pinia.mjs:1709
    <anonymous> user.ts:9

I don't understand this. Even with setActivePinia it still does not work. And the app is mounted at the end of main.ts. So why does it not work and how can I fix it?

You're not supposed to call setActivePinia in main. And, even if you do, you must do it after app.use(pinia).

The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The error suggests that you used a store before app.use(pinia), likely due to incorrect import order or store use. As said, setActivePinia is not needed but it's not supposed to cause this error

To clear up some confusion, I have reverted the code back to what I had before I tried setActivePinia and the error still occurs (yes, I did reload the page after the change).

I found what's wrong, see my answer. Thanks for all the hints.

The issue has to do with something else, unrelated to App.vue itself.
In the user store I was using another store:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useErrors } from '@/stores/errors'

const errors = useErrors()

export const useUser = defineStore('user', () => {
  const currentLoginToken = ref<string | null>(null)
  // ...
})

The problem is that const errors = useErrors() is in the root level and thus already executed at import time which is before anything else runs in App.vue and since main.ts imports App.vue, it also runs before anything in main.ts runs and thus causes the error.
main.ts ---- imports ----> App.vue ---- imports ----> user.ts ---- uses ----> useErrors()
And useErrors() would run before app.use(createPinia()). So to solve this, move the line to inside the store:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useErrors } from '@/stores/errors'

export const useUser = defineStore('user', () => {
  const errors = useErrors()
  const currentLoginToken = ref<string | null>(null)
  // ...
})


I see, in this case, it would have been very helpful to see the code that was in your users store. Either way, I'm glad your problem was resolved!

@flint I agree with you. I should have posted an MCVE, however in the hurry of getting problem after problem fixed, I didn't do my due diligence. I hope the answer still helps others.

It seems there might be a misunderstanding; setActivePinia is not necessary in order to use Pinia in your application, it's used for testing. app.use(pinia) will attach your Pinia instance to your application. Simply removing the line setActivePinia(pinia) should accomplish what you want

Looks like I did not explain properly. Before I did not have setActivePinia in the code and it didn't work so I tried it with setActivePinia. Just app.use(createPinia()) was in the code before. I also tried putting pinia in a separate variable but that didn't work either. I can use the store from other components but not from App.vue.

I see. In that case, setActivePinia is not your answer and the problem lies elsewhere. What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Is there an error message you're getting, or just no values in the store?

The error message is the same as the one in my question: Uncaught Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Are you trying to use a store before calling "app.use(pinia)"? See https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html for help. This will fail in production..
